# Networking a .py file, with a .bat and .ini

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd, network-programming, package

Here is my problem :

I wrote a python script which works,but only on my machine (when I run it in my interpreter).

I also wrote .bat and .ini file (as I already did for other scripts which work), and when I run the .bat, it says :

```
import xlsxwriter
ImportError: No module named xlsxwriter
```

(The other batches I wrote for ohter scripts works well)

xlsxwriter is a new package I installed for this script (I installed in my interpreter (pyCharms))...

so why my batch doesn't work while my script does ? Do I have to dwnld/install the package/module somewhere else ? Where ?

When the problem is fixed, I'd like to share my .py ,.bat, .ini files with my colleagues so they can run the batch as well. What will be the steps ? Will they have to install/dwld the package as well ?

Comment: Have you tried pip install xlsxwriter on a terminal/cmd?

Comment: Without actual code, we can't say much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `xlsxwriter` must be present on any machine on which you want to run your script.  The easiest way to install it on the host is with `pip`:

```
$ pip install xlsxwriter
```

You can also include a `requirements.txt` file with your script that includes `xlsxwriter` in it, and users can run the following:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

More on pip and distributing packages that have 3rd party dependencies:  https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/